# Missing Filmic Looks in Blender 2.81

Tags: rendering, color-management, filmic-blender

Filmic has been shipped with Blender as a default render View Transform since 2.79a. I'm using Blender 2.81, but I'm missing the following Looks from the dropdown:

- Base Contrast
- Greyscale
- False Colour

This is a screenshot from my computer showing the incomplete list:

[image]

They are still listed [in the README inside the repo](https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender#look-transforms), so I guess they should still be included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Blender 2.80 the OCIO configuration has been updated.

- *Base Contrast* has been removed from the list of *Looks* since it's equivalent to *None*.
- *False Color* is now a separate *View Transform*.
- *Grayscale* has been removed from the *Looks* without a replacement, you would have to use the compositor for this or use a custom OCIO configuration.

The linked repository is maintained by Troy Sobotka, which is independent of Blender's development. The implementation of the *Filmic* view transform for Blender was based on his work, but the current OCIO configuration in Blender differs from the state in the repository.

The official documentation for Blender is the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html#render). If you're missing features that are documented in the manual, please write a [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/) and tag the [documentation project](https://developer.blender.org/project/view/53/).

Comment: You can edit the config.ocio file and include the color matrix to do this directly using the color management.

Comment: looks:
  - !<Look>
    name: Greyscale
    process_space: Filmic Log Encoding
    transform: !<MatrixTransform> {matrix: [0.2126729, 0.7151521, 0.0721750, 0, 0.2126729, 0.7151521, 0.0721750, 0, 0.2126729, 0.7151521, 0.0721750, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}

Comment: I can't speak for Troy, but there are different ideas (and reasons why)  the filmic transforms were created, named and implemented.

Comment: Note that the way grayscale is implemented in the filmic blender does take into consideration the weight of the primaries to calculate the conversion to black and white. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112525/how-does-cycles-calculate-rgb-to-bw/112554#112554

Comment: @cegaton What I meant to say was that Blender's repository and its manual should be used as official reference since Blender's developers aren't obligated to include changes from the community. If Troy should decide to implement new view transforms in the linked repository, they aren't necessarily included in Blender. I wanted to point this out since the differences between Troy's repository and Blender is what sparked the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the ocio configuration from blender, and use the one used by the author of Filmic Blender directly

https://sobotka.github.io/filmic-blender/

[image]

Alternatively, to use the **Greyscale look**, you can manually edit the `config.ocio` file in the `colormanagement` folder and add the following stanza in the `looks` section:

```
looks:
  - !<Look>
    name: Greyscale
    process_space: Filmic Log Encoding
    transform: !<MatrixTransform> {matrix: [0.2126729, 0.7151521, 0.0721750, 0, 0.2126729, 0.7151521, 0.0721750, 0, 0.2126729, 0.7151521, 0.0721750, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}
```