# Does the filmic grayscale look still exist?

Tags: color-management

In older versions of filmic there was a grayscale option.
But ever since it was officially bundled with Blender it seems to have vanished.
So does the Filmic implementation in default Blender still have the grayscale look somewhere?

Comment: There is no specific greyscale look but you can achieve grayscale by using an RGBtoBW node in the compositor.

Comment: Agree with the above. Now that doesn't allow to have a BW viewport, but the BF is working on making the compositing visible from the viewport. So once that is done, seeing what you do in the viewport in BW will be possible again. More details [on this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/163404/53447)